# Why do we call a disjunction of literals of which none is positive a goal clause?

Tags: prolog, logic

I think I know the meaning of **goal clauses** and **horn clauses**, but I'm quite confused about why people name a disjunction of literals of which none is positive a **goal clause**?

What's the goal here?

Comment: Yep...I'm  just confused why name it goal clause.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You're right, I'm not familiar with logical languages. And I'm sorry that I'm not sure about 'the head of the clause' you mentioned. I only know that the horn clause can be expressed in implication form, but that still doesn't give me any idea about why name a horn clause without any positive literal a goal clause. Could you shed some light on it, even if it may not be right?

Comment: Really thanks for your concern. I'll wait :)

Comment: Of interest: [http://www.learnprolognow.org/slides/official/Horn.pdf](http://www.learnprolognow.org/slides/official/Horn.pdf)

Comment: Of interest: [Excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=lsvSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA360&lpg=PA360&dq=goal+clause+disjunction&source=bl&ots=4uUsjoL9Ej&sig=ET8yskK-RhRCkQBcx3si2S8GPNE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirpqmDmY7VAhWJdz4KHV3PAsEQ6AEIdzAQ#v=onepage&q=goal%20clause%20disjunction&f=false) from "Automated Theorem Proving: A Logical" by D.W. Loveland

Comment: Of interest: Wolfram MathWorld [Horn clause](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornClause.html)

Comment: Of interest: Wiktionary [Horn Clause](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Horn_clause)

Comment: Of interest: Simple Wikipedia [Horn Clause](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause)

Comment: Of interest: [The University of Edinburgh](http://www.ed.ac.uk/informatics/) Course [Prolog Programming for Automated Reasoning students](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ar/ARPROLOG/) Lecture 10 - [Logic Programming](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ar/ARPROLOG/slides/lect10.pdf)

Comment: Really thanks for your time! I roughly checked your links, but still haven't get what I'm looking for. Maybe we have some misunderstanding...I've update my question, and hope this time it will be clearer. I'm so sorry for my poor English:(

Comment: Of interest: [SLD resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution)

Comment: Of interest: [Logic Programming](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~rak/papers/History.pdf)

Comment: Of interest: [Lecture 16: Logic I](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs221/2016/lectures/logic1.pdf) This is a good one for your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll check these links later :)

Comment: Of interest: [SLD-Resolution](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/8710/f03/ch3.pdf)

Comment: because having the program, we run it with e.g. `:- A,B.` i.e. `(A,B)=>T` i.e. `~A \/ ~B`.

Comment: Of interest: [Logic Programming](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/lp/lectures/lp-all.pdf) by Frank Pfenning.

Comment: Of interest: [Constraint Logic Programming: A Survey](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8440/00c1d84f547449d8f5baf3f62afe2a49965e.pdf)

Comment: The idea of calling the clause goal is that the facts and rules in your Prolog program define a knowledge base. If you want to query the KB, you want to know if your query-clause is derivable from it. Without the query, you could only blindly enumerate all the consequences of your KB. Instead your query serves as the goal to reach with a derivation. Usually this is done backwards, starting with the goal and trying to fulfill its prerequisites and continue this process until you have reached only facts. To emphasize this, people often call the query clause just "the goal".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three types of [Horn clauses](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause)

definite clause: ¬ p ∨ ¬ q ∨ ⋯ ∨ ¬ t ∨ u
fact: u
goal clause: ¬ p ∨ ¬ q ∨ ⋯ ∨ ¬ t

which relate to Prolog.
Example Prolog from [Adventures in Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/apreface.php)

A definite clause is a Prolog [rule](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a5rules.php):

```
where_food(X,Y) :-  
  location(X,Y),
  edible(X).
```

A fact is a Prolog [fact](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a2facts.php):

```
room(kitchen).
```

A goal clause is a Prolog [query](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a4comqry.php):

```
location(X, kitchen), edible(X).
```

Another way of looking at three common with Prolog uses `head`, `body` and `:-`.

A rule is `head :- body.`
A fact is `head.`
A query is `body.`

A body is made up of calls to predicates (head), so a body can look like this `A,B,C`.

When you use a query it is really

```
goal :- body.
```

or

```
goal <- A,B,C
```

or

```
location(X, kitchen), edible(X) ⊃ goal
```

### A Prolog example

Facts

```
location(apple, kitchen).
location(crackers, kitchen).
location(flashlight, desk).

edible(apple).
edible(crackers).
```

Goal clause

```
location(X, kitchen), edible(X).
```

Answer

```
X = apple
X = crackers
```

### Earlier answer

Starting with a predicate in Prolog

```
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X, Z) , ancestor(Z,Y).
```

where `ancestor(X,Y)` is know as the head clause and `parent(X, Z) , ancestor(Z,Y)` is known as the body.

Converting the Prolog to an implication
`:-` is `⊃`
`,` is `∧`
and the implication is reversed.

```
(parent(X,Z) ∧ ancestor(Z,Y)) ⊃ ancestor(X,Y)
```

converting the conjunction (∧) of literals into a disjunction (∨) of literals

```
not parent(X,Z) ∨ not ancestor(Z,Y) ∨ ancestor(X,Y)
```

results in `not parent(X,Z) ∨ not ancestor(Z,Y)` which is the Prolog body or in your question the goal clause.

In other words the goal clause are the statements that need to be satisfied in order to achieve the goal which is the Prolog head `ancestor(X,Y)`.

To see an example of using the Prolog ancestor see [Prolog/Recursive Rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Recursive_Rules). Note that the rule given in this example is only one of the two that are used to define ancestor with the missing Prolog rule being `ancestor(A, B) :- parent(A, B).`

### References

The University of Edinburgh Course: Prolog Programming for Automated Reasoning students - Lecture 10 - [Logic Programming](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ar/ARPROLOG/slides/lect10.pdf)

[Goal clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause#Definition) definition from Wikipedia -

`a Horn clause without a positive literal is sometimes called a goal clause`
or `¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ ... ∨ ¬t`

SWI-Prolog [Glossary of Terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary)

[Prolog/Recursive Rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Recursive_Rules)

[Foundations of Logic](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=TeKpCAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Foundations%20of%20Logic%20Programming&ots=wLoN6OROlT&sig=_tWV2OLVlQu6Z9dGJwmJR18KQ4Y#v=onepage&q=goal%20&f=false) ([WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/864586957))

### Try the Prolog online

Using [swish](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/XlRdOBoS.pl) (Prolog rules are already entered with this link)
In the lower right by `?-` where it says `your query goes here ...` enter `ancestor(X, john).`
Then in the lower right click `Run!`
Above that you should see an ancestor of john
`X=david`
Under that click `Next` and you should see another ancestor of john
`X=jim`
keep clicking `Next` to see other ancestors and then finally you should see
`false` meaning there are no more valid answers.

### An excerpt

From [Logic Programming](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/lp/lectures/lp-all.pdf) by Frank Pfenning

> To make the transition from inference rules to logic programming we
> need to impose a particular strategy. Two fundamental ideas suggest
> themselves: we could either search backward from the conjecture,
> growing a (potential) proof tree upwards, or we could work forwards
> from the axioms applying rules until we arrive at the conjecture. We
> call the ﬁrst one goal-directed and the second one forward-reasoning.

### How to search

OP comment

> Could you tell me how you do such searches, 'cause when I run into
> some complex problems I usually don't know how to search necessary
> resources

Normally I would have the OP (original poster) ask that as another question, but since it is more of a subjective than objective question it will get shot down at SO (StackOverflow) with down and close votes and I can use examples related to the original question so I will answer it here.

When searching the path to success is to figure out the current terminology used by the experts in the area and which key words in that terminology are relevant to what you seek. Sometimes I know the key words off the top of my head, as with this question with `disjunction of literals` and `goal` I knew they were key terms in logic, reasoning, theorem proving and logic languages. Other times I am guessing or in the dark as with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41575278/1243762).

One way that sometimes yields success when trying to learn the current terminology is to search for [review articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Review_article) which typically have `survey` in the title and thus `survey` is a good keyword. e.g. using [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/) with [horn clause survey](https://www.semanticscholar.org/search?q=horn%20clause%20survey&sort=relevance&ae=false) finds on first page [Constraint Logic Programming: A Survey](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8440/00c1d84f547449d8f5baf3f62afe2a49965e.pdf)

As an example of searching for the canonical form of math expressions with `math canonical form` little of relevance was found but after finding that `standard from` was more commonly used, better results were obtained.

Sometimes it is not words that help you find the answer and search engines that rely on words will fail you. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12881980/1243762) a type of search I see every few weeks or so involves finding the pattern/formula/etc. that generates a sequence of numbers and you only know part of the sequence, and typically the start of the sequence. This is were a search using [OEIS](http://oeisf.org/index.html) (The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®) comes in handy. Another type of search engine related to math is [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/). So be attentive to the fact that there are other kinds of search engines

Once you have the key words then as @WillNess notes you some times query for them as single words `goal clause`, but some times as exact words in quotes `"goal clause"`. For this question using an exact word returned better results.

The next thing to realize is the source of the information often corresponds with quality of information.

- Sources from university courses, online digital scientific libraries and books are high on my [list](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7143/268)
- PDF (Postscript Document Format). The reason for PDF is that it is common to write technical professional papers with [LaTeX](http://exponential_exponent_normal_form) which are then output as PDF. The old format was PS (PostScript) but I rarely see that with newer papers. Thus `pdf` is a good search term to add.
- Then sites from the creators such as [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/), [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/)
- Sites that are obviously good such as [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)
- Blog entries by the experts; most blogs are not by the experts.

Other search engines I use related to computer science technical papers are:

- [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/index)
- [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/)
- [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/)
- [Microsoft Academic](https://academic.microsoft.com/)
- [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/)
- [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/)
- [dblp](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/)

and of course you can always query for other [academic search engines](https://www.google.com/search?q=acedemic%20search%20engines&ie=&oe=#q=academic%20search%20engines&spf=1500463958476)

If you have only one or two documents that appeal to you but still don't have enough detail then start working down the references noted in those documents. This can be challenging as years ago many of the articles were only published in professional journals and are not freely available. However it is common to find those articles freely available if one of the authors is a professor and you can find the document listed under their public pages where they teach. [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/index) is really good for finding referenced documents.

If you are using an existing SO answer then check the tag to see if they are a [top answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/f%23/topusers) and remember that the accepted answer may not be the best answer and that any answer may not be a correct answer to your question.

Then it is a matter of reading several of the articles to see what information is current and if there is consistency.

Some fields are moving fast and changing rapidly even in the time span of the last 20 years of the Internet. Here is an example where one [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) made a significant change. If you are not aware of this paper in the area it relates you will probably be confused by research that happened before the paper and research based on the paper. To find such papers note the significant number of citations, at present [18658](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Attention%20Is%20All%20You%20Need&author=Ashish%20Vaswani&author=Noam%20Shazeer&publication_date=2017/12/06&arxiv_id=1706.03762).

Don't be hesitant to spend upwards of an hour just searching and then a few more to a full day just reading. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37117089/1243762) I spent over four hours searching and reading and still could not find an answer. After finally running out of things to try I posted the question only to find it can not be done and is not documented. The answer was by someone I know to be an expert in F#.

Lastly don't be afraid to leave bread crumbs, e.g. your own personal notes as I do with `Of interest:` comments or in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42627198/1243762). You will often use the same search terms over and over again and if you have enough posted on the Internet will start to run into your own post. After a while you will realize that if you only left bread crumbs there it would have made your life easier.

The rest is just years of experience and diligence.

Also sometimes asking an SO question requesting help with which keywords to use sometimes gets answers and sometimes get shot down.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I'm a English learner, so I'm sorry if there is any misunderstanding. I'm very appreciating that you explained to me what is horn clause and what is goal clause in detail. And you mentioned _the goal clause are the statements that need to be satisfied in order to achieve the goal which is the Prolog head ancestor(X,Y)_. But to me, _ancestor(X, Y)_ is more like a goal, and the goal clause is more like a premise. So I'm still confused why people name the premise a goal clause?

Comment: Thanks you:)! Could you tell me how you do such searches, 'cause when I run into some complex problems I usually don't know how to search necessary resources but ask...

Comment: @SherwinChen google. e.g. [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=goal+clause),  or [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22goal+clause%22)

Comment: Thank you for your help:) I'm very grateful that you shared your personal experience and insight of searching.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the accepted answer; but, oh well. :p

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I'm sorry for that. I accepted it because I highly valued his effort and his insight of searching- -. I know that your answer perfectly solves my question and I've voted it. Sorry again:(

Comment: Of interest: [Tips on Literature Surveys](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/graduate/CMSC601/Spring12/lit-survey.html) - More information related to searching.

Comment: Of interest: [unpaywall](http://unpaywall.org/) - This New Browser Plug-in Lets You Access Millions of Scientific Papers For Free. Just found this, have not tried it.

Answer (score 5):

This is my personal understanding, but I'll do my best to relay it.

---

**What's the intuition behind a 'goal clause'? Why call it that at all?**

First let's confirm some definitions:

- A *clause* is defined as a disjunction of literals. Furthermore, since the disjunction operator is *associative*, that is, the following property applies:

  [image]

  a clause can further be thought of as a disjunction of 'sub' clauses, that is, a clause like

  <sub>[image]</sub>
  , 
  could be 'split' into two parts representing "sub" clauses

  <sub>[image]</sub>

  and

  <sub>[image]</sub>
- a *Horn clause* is defined as a clause with *at most* one positive literal; as such, it can take three recognisable forms:

  1. the 'full' form: 

     <sub>[image]</sub>

     , which is known as a *definite* clause
  2. the form lacking any negative literals:

     <sub>[image]</sub>

     , which is known as a *factual clause* (or simply a *fact*).
  3. the form lacking a positive literal:

     <sub>[image]</sub>

     , which is known as a *goal clause*

If you compare forms 1 and 3, you will see that you could split form 1 into two parts (or sub-clauses): one clause which is essentially in the form of a 'goal clause', and one which is a standalone positive literal, which we will call the *head*.

Furthermore, this Horn clause can be rearranged into *implication form* as follows:

[image]

The *implication form* might also be referred to as a 'relationship', since, if we are given this particular horn clause as a premise, we are essentially being told that "it applies that *if* the first part is true, then the second must also necessarily be true".

The name *goal clause* should now start to make more sense. From the rules of natural deduction we know that, given

  <sub>[image]</sub>

, if we also manage to prove

  <sub>[image]</sub>

, then we can deduce 

  <sub>[image]</sub>
. Therefore given a horn clause in implication form, which essentially reads "Goal implies Head", if we show that the "Goal" is true, we can logically conclude that the Head part *must also* necessarily be true. Therefore the "Goal" part of a Horn clause is the part for which we need to discover whether it is satisfiable or not, in order to conclude whether the Head is then true as a result.

Note that what I'm now referring to as "Goal" in *this* context is no longer in "*clause*" form, since the "Goal" is now in the form of a conjunction of (positive) literals, as opposed to a *disjunction* of literals. In effect, the logical statement that I'm now referring to as the "Goal" I'm trying to prove, is in fact equivalent to the negation of what we referred to earlier as the "Goal *clause*" (i.e. the statement formed by the disjunction of the negative literals). So we could think of the "Goal clause" as the relevant statement in clause-form, i.e. corresponding to the negation of the Goal we're trying to prove; it is the clause part of the Horn clause (when written in "clause" form) that gets negated, giving rise to the Goal component in the implication form.

---

**But what's the point of even talking about Goals and Goal clauses. Do you ever get standalone "Goals" / "Goal clauses" in a database?**

Sure. Note that a *standalone* "Goal clause" statement is equivalent to the statement "Goal implies False" (or more to the point, assuming the "Goal" is true proves nothing further / does not yield any more information). So a standalone "Goal clause" is essentially equivalent to a Goal without a Head, i.e. a Goal that when satisfied proves nothing else.

If we have a Goal without a Head, then we are essentially being asked to evaluate whether the Goal can be satisfied, but without relating this to a Head that needs to be deduced. The notion of having to evaluate a goal just for the fun of it might sound odd, but it starts making sense in Prolog terms, when you realise that *some* predicates cause *side-effects* to the system. So for instance, in Prolog, statements like these:

```
:- dynamic pred1, pred2.
:- writeln("I have just reached the end of the database file").
```

will be evaluated *on the spot* at the point of reading in the database (i.e. your prolog "script"), and have side-effects on the system, but without resulting in a fact or relationship entering the knowledge-database. In Prolog, such "headless" statements which are intended to be evaluated on-the-spot and cause side-effects to the runtime environment, are often called *directives*.

---

**What's the relationship between a Goal clause and a Query? Are they the same?**

Well, no. They're related. Specifically, a query is performed (under the hood) by attempting to prove that the Goal *cannot* be satisfied, i.e. we start by assuming it is false (or equivalently, that the Goal *clause* is true). Prolog then goes through the database, and tries to match the literals, or tries out substitutions, just like it would if it was trying to satisfy a Goal with the intent of deducing the Head of a definite clause. If we come across a substitution that satisfies this goal, then, in the context of the query, this leads to a contradiction. A query therefore reports the terms for which the negation of the goal under those substitutions leads to a contradiction. In other words, these substitutions are the ones for which the goal is satisfied.

*EDIT:* (addressing comments).

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_syntax_and_semantics#Evaluation):

> Execution of a Prolog program is initiated by the user's posting of a single goal, called the query. Logically, the Prolog engine tries to find a resolution refutation of the negated query. The resolution method used by Prolog is called [SLD resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution). If the negated query can be refuted, it follows that the query, with the appropriate variable bindings in place, is a logical consequence of the program. In that case, all generated variable bindings are reported to the user, and the query is said to have succeeded

Here is an example of how a query might be implemented under the hood. Say you have the following knowledge-base:

```
a.        % premise 1
b :- a.   % premise 2
% ... plus many other facts and relationships not involving a or b
```

The prolog statement `b :- a` essentially corresponds to the logical statement `a -> b`, which is equivalent to the logical statement `¬a v b`. So we are given `¬a v b` and `a` as premises.

Now let's say you ask the following query:

```
?- b.
```

This is equivalent to saying "Hey, Prolog, is the statement `b is true`, true or false?"

It would be very inefficient to just start evaluating statements randomly to see if they happen to yield `b is true` as a result. So instead, in order to *prove* (in the mathematical sense) that `b is true`, Prolog reasons as follows: "I will instead start by assuming that `b` is in fact false, and start plugging it in, in the relevant premises. If this assumption forces a falsification in any of my premises which I hold to be true, then this proves that this assumption does not in fact hold, and therefore b is *proven* to be true."

Programmatically this might go like this:

- Step 1: Assume ¬b
- Step 2: Find all premises involving the literal `b` and test them
- Step 3: b takes part in premise `¬a v b`. This needs to evaluate to true because it's a premise. Since b is assumed to be false, for this premise to evaluate to true, `a` needs to be false.
- Step 4: a is true (premise 1). This contradicts Step 3.

Therefore the assumption `¬b` leads to a contradiction, and is therefore false. This proves the statement `b is true`.

This example only involved literals. When predicates with variables are involved, there may be some variable substitutions for which "¬b" leads to a contradiction in a similar way. Therefore we conclude that "b is proven to be true for the following substitutions", and Prolog will then report the relevant substitutions for which b is proven to be true.

Comment: Thank you:) I think you've perfectly answer my question. But the last part about query is not very clear to me. Why _is a query performed by attempting to prove that the Goal cannot be satisfied_? Could you give me some further explanations on this (or maybe an example)?

Comment: There is no _reason_ as such. This is just how the mathematical engine does it "under the hood". It could have approached it some other way, but presumably this is a more efficient implementation. But in practice you see none of this; all you see is that you put a Goal as a query term, and you get back valid substitutions as answers.

Comment: Read the [opening sentence in the wikipedia entry for Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Syntax_and_semantics) as well :)  (edit: or the article linked there which explains in detail, if you're feeling brave! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_syntax_and_semantics )

Comment: I've thought what you put up here for a while. I think maybe I misunderstood what you said. Were you saying _reductio ad absurdum_? For example, if I query *q*, the query program assumes *q* is not true, and infers something against the fact in knowledge base.

Comment: I wouldn't call this reduction ad absurdum. The whole thing relies on the equivalence of a -> b == ¬a v b.  I'll try to put an example of this, athough I'm sure I'll confuse you more than I'll clear things up, hahah. Honestly though, it doesn't matter that much. If you're interested, read up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_syntax_and_semantics#Evaluation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution , but this is just more a case of how prolog implements queries as "resolution refutation". The only important message here is that the terms "Goal" and "Query" aren't synonymous.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help:) I've check the wiki link, it describes two strategies: one is resolution refutation and the other is sound like backward chaining to me(I noticed it says it's backtracking). IMHO "resolution refutation" is just a way for computer to process reduction ad absurdum. I don't know if there is any misunderstanding, welcome to point it out:)

Comment: I wouldn't call this reductio ad absurdum. This is proof by contradiction. (the two terms are not synonymous). But yes, prolog essentially tries to perform proof by contradiction. Backtracking is the recursive process by which prolog doesn't stop after the first proof, but continues to see if there are _more_ variable substitutions for which you could prove your goal by contradiction (and therefore this is a mechanism for producing all the valid substitutions possible).

Comment: Hmm... Could you please take some time to explain to me the difference between reductio ad absurdum and proof by contradiction? 'Cause I thought they're same- -.

Comment: Well, for me, reductio ad absurdum is showing that an argument leads to an absurd absolute. An absurd absolute is used as an argument against the assumption that produced it, but may not necessarily be the kind of statement that qualifies as a clear-cut contradiction in the mathematical sense. Proof by contradiction is more related to formal logic in a mathematical sense, whereas an absurd absolute relates to a more conversational context, and may well only be "absurd" or "absolute" in a very subjective sense.

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry for response late, I've been thinking what you said for a while today, maybe because of my poor English, I still cannot tell the difference very well. Were you suggesting that proof by contradiction is stricter in a mathematical sense than reductio ad absurdum? And I cannot well understand that "An absurd absolute is used as an argument against the assumption that produced it, but may not necessarily be the kind of statement that qualifies as a clear-cut contradiction in mathematical sense", could you give me a concrete example for it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting. In formal logic you have clear-cut proof by contradiction (PBC). In debates you have reductio ad absurdum (RAA). To the extent that a contradiction is the equivalent of an "absurdity" in formal logic, you could say PBC is RAA in the context of logic. But in debates RAA might take the form "Assume P, P->Q. I consider Q to be an absurd outcome (e.g. "there is a God"), therefore P must be false". The problem is, what is absurd to you (e.g. because you are atheist) may well be subjective or debatable, or even simply a literary device, whereas logic is just math.

Comment: Oh...Thank your! this time I finally get it:)